# Checking if develop branch has been merged into feature branch?

Tags: git

I have a script bumping the version and making a commit with the bump and tagging it. The issue I am having is making sure develop gets fetched from remote then merged into feature branch to insure no conflicts during the PR merge.

How do I check that the feature and develop are <strike>in sync</strike> merged?

Comment: "in sync" and "merged into" are different: two labels are in sync if they refer to the same commit, but branch A is fully merged into branch B if the commit identified by A is a predecessor of that identified by B.  To put it another way, B can be way ahead of A, rather than the two being in sync.

Comment: So what I am looking for is if the commit at the head of develop branch is somewhere before the head of the feature branch?

Comment: It sounds like that, yes.  Note that `git branch --merged` and `git branch --no-merged` use that test, but there's a simpler method if you only want to check one particular pair: `git merge-base --is-ancestor` tests a particular commit pair.  So `git merge-base --is-ancestor A B` returns true (exits with status 0) if `A` identifies a commit that is an ancestor of whatever commit `B` identifies.  (Note that `is-ancestor` treats equal commits as "is ancestor".)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `git branch` command will show you branches that are merged, or are not merged.  For instance, if you are on branch `main` and branch `side` was merged in at some point, but another branch `ahead` has not yet been merged:

```
$ git branch --merged
* main
  side
$ git branch --no-merged
  ahead
$
```

It's possible (but somewhat painful) to use this to check.  But if you just want to test one *specific* pair of branches (or indeed any specific pair of commits), the "is / is-not merged" quality is simply whether one is an ancestor of another, in terms of the commit graph.

The `git merge-base` command has a mode in which it performs this test, for two specific commits (which you may specify in any form listed in [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)):

```
$ if git merge-base --is-ancestor side main; then
>     echo side is merged into main
> fi
side is merged into main
$
```

The test that `git branch --merged` uses (for each branch, comparing it to the current branch) is the same as the test `git merge-base --is-ancestor` uses, i.e., the SHA-1 that the first commit (here `side^{commit}`) is an ancestor of the current branch's tip commit.  (A commit is considered an ancestor of itself, so you always get your own current branch from `git branch --merged`.  Assuming of course that you are on a branch in the first place—if you're in "detached HEAD" state, the list of all named branches does not include your detached HEAD.)

Comment: I tried this command with a new branch, not merged nor committed, and the answer is still "is merged"...

Comment: A new branch you just created may well already be merged. If you create the new branch *and then add a commit to it* it will no longer be merged. (This is because branch *names* don't really mean anything here: the test is whether commit *X* is an ancestor of commit *Y*. The branch name is merely a way of identifying some particular commit. Making a commit while on a given branch has the side effect of changing the branch name to point to the new commit just made, while growing the commit graph.)

Comment: you are right, once committed, the answer is empty, so, it's not merged. Thanks!